# Ck editor is not working after putting it in innerHTML to replace a div with the Ckeditor textarea

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, ckeditor

today i have been assigned a work where i have an input text and if someone will click on it then it will replace it with a textaread which has ckeditor enabled on it. I already enabled the ckeditor with the textarea but when i am going trying to replace a div with the ckeditor enabled textarea then it is just showing me a simple textarea not with ckeditor enabled on it.Below is the coding for it:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myJDFunction1()
{
document.getElementById("Hide1").innerHTML='<textarea class="ckeditor" id="typingarea2" name="typingarea2"></textarea>';
}

</script>



<div id="Hide1">
    <textarea name="Answer1" onclick="myJDFunction1()"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: where r u keeping those configuration file of ckeditor?

Comment: I'm keeping the config file inside of ckeditor folder

Answer (score 1):

You have to call

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'typingarea2' );
```

since editor instances are created automatically (by class) only when the page is being loaded.

Also a better way is:

```
function myJDFunction1() {
    CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'Hide1' );
}

<div id="Hide1" onclick="myJDFunction1()">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Well it's been working as i whenever i am clicking on the textbox then it is showing me the ckeditor but the problem is that i want to remove the textbox with the ckeditor..Thanks for your answer as it solve 50% of my problem

Comment: Use `CKEDITOR.instances.instanceName.destroy()` to remove editor.

Answer (score 1):

Try using jquery plugin adater to call CKEDITOR [Jquery Plugin for CKEDITOR](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-for-jQuery)

1. import jquery javascript files.
2. import jquery ckeditor adapter  "/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js".
3. bind your CKEDITOR to the DOM Element.

   ```
    $('#Hide1').ckeditor();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" id="Hide1" onclick='document.getElementById("Hide1").innerHTML=
"<textarea class=ckeditor id=typingarea2 name=typingarea2></textarea>"'>text editor</a>
```