# Use the CKEDITOR.replace() method to replace a dynamic <textarea> element with CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have followed this threads:

1. [how to open reply form under comments div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842585/how-to-open-reply-form-under-comments-div);
2. [Ck editor is not working after putting it in innerHTML to replace a div with the Ckeditor textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382622/ck-editor-is-not-working-after-putting-it-in-innerhtml-to-replace-a-div-with-the)
3. [CKeditor with multible dynamic textareas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261108/ckeditor-with-multible-dynamic-textareas)

as a foundation in building a simple blog commenting application. The simple HTMl layout is shown below:

I am using the jQuery .toggle() function to hide, show the hidden comment form with jQuery.

I am also using the parent(); children() and next() jquery methods to traverse the DOM and select the textarea element of the displayed form so as to assign the 'name attribute' to it.

I then wish to replace the dynamic (textarea name="content") with a CKEditor instance.

However, when I toggle the comment form, (the name="content") attribute is assigned, but what appears is a simple textarea not with ckeditor enabled on it.

How can I make each new dynamically created textareas use CKeditor?

**Note that when I hardcode the name='content' attribute value pair into any of the text areas, that textarea is converted into a rich text editor.**

```
                <div>
                  <div>
                    Some message over here
                   </div>
                   <div style = "height:10px;"> <a class="reply" id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');" >Reply</a></div>                                        
                </div>
                <div class ="replymsgbox" id="newboxes1">
                    <form id="frmComment" novalidate="novalidate" method="POST" name="frmComment">
                        <textarea id="comment_text" class=""></textarea>
                    </form>
                </div>   
                <div>
                  <div>
                    Some message over here
                   </div>
                  <div style = "height:10px;"> <a class="reply" id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');" >Reply</a></div>                                        
                </div>
                <div class="replymsgbox" id="newboxes2">
                    <form id="frmComment" novalidate="novalidate" method="POST" name="frmComment">
                        <textarea id="comment_text" class="" ></textarea>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

**#Assign name attribute and toggle the comment form**

---

```
                <script src="views/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
                     $('.replymsgbox').each(function(index) {
                          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
                               $(this).show(200);
                          }
                          else {
                               $(this).hide(600);
                          }
                     });
                }
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $('a.reply').on("click", function(e){   
                 $(this).parent("div").parent("div").next("div").children('form').children('textarea').attr( "name", "content" );
                });
                </script>
```

**#Adding CKEditor to my Page**

---

```
                <script src="libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>  
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {    
                    if(CKEDITOR) 
                    {
                        // Replace the <textarea name = "content"> with a CKEditor instance. 
                        CKEDITOR.replace('content');
                    }
                });
                </script>
```

Comment: Hey, did you solve this maybe? I came up with the same problem, `CKEDITOR.replace()` won't find dynamically created element.